# Tokenize a JavaScript String depending on the characters

Tags: javascript, parsing

In JavaScript, let's say I have a String like `"23+var-5/422*b"`.

I want to split this String so that I get `[23,+,var,-,5,/,422,*,b]`.

I want to tokenize it so that I split the string into 3 types of tokens:

- Numerical literals, `[0-9]`.
- String literals, `[A-z]`.
- Operator characters, `[-+*/]`.

So basically, go through the string, and *for each "cluster of characters" that share the same class* (each with 1 or more characters), convert that into a token.

I could probably use a for loop, comparing each character with each class, and manually create a token every time the current "character class" changes... it would be very tedious and use many variables and loops.

Does anyone know a more elegant (less verbose) way to get there?

Comment: Do you want to annotate the type of token, or really just split into an array?

Comment: Just spitting it out into an array would be great :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A global regexp [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will do this for you:

```
var str = "23+var-5/422*b";
var arr = str.match(/[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+|[-+*/]/g); // notice the creation of one token
                                                 // per operator (even if consecutive)
```

However, it simply ignores invalid characters instead of erroring out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it using Regex. Obviously the code can be simplified more if you use Underscore.js or CoffeeScript. So here's a longer version using vanilla JS:

```
var s = "23+var-5/422*b"; // your string
var re1 = /[0-9]/; // Regex for numerals
var re2 = /[a-zA-Z]/; // Regex for roman chars
var re3 = /[-+*\/]/; // Regex you wanted for operators
// Helper function, return true if n none-negative
function nonNegative(n) {
    return n >= 0;
}
// helper function: add any none-negative n to array arr
function addNonNegative(n, arr) {
    if (nonNegative(n)) {arr.push(n)};
}
// The main function to split string s
function split(s) {
    var result = []; // The result array, initialized

    // Do while string s is none empty.
    while(s.length > 0) {
        // The order of indices of regex found
        var order = [];
        // search for index or which the regex occurs, then if  that index is none-negative, add it to the 'order' array
        addNonNegative(s.search(re1), order);
        addNonNegative(s.search(re2), order);
        addNonNegative(s.search(re3), order);
        // sort the order array
        order = order.sort(); 
        // variables to slice the string s.
        // start is always 0. Marks the starting index of the   first   matched regex
        var start = order.shift(); 
        // Marks the starting index of the second matched regex
        var end = order.shift(); //  end is the second result in    order
        result.push(s.slice(start, end)); // slice the string s     from    start to end
        // update s so that exclude what was sliced before
        s = s.slice(end);
        // boundary condition: finally when end is null once all    regex   have been pulled, set s = ""
        if (end == null) {s = ""};
    }
    return result;
}
```